# How to create a(n) (animated) wind map?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, r

I would like to create a wind map like here: [www.windytv.com](https://www.windytv.com/). It doesn't need to be animated. However, an animation would be a nice final add-on. I am working with ArcGIS, QGIS, several python libaries and R. However I have no clue where to get started and how to accomplish the task.

Comment: I would start by deciding what software I wanted to use to try and do this. Let's say I choose ArcGIS Desktop because that is what I have on my laptop. My next step would be to search on 'ArcGIS wind map'.  If I found an idea and got stuck implementing it then I would consider asking a question that describes what I want to do, what I tried and where I got stuck.

Comment: Is there a possibility to ask a general question w/o specification? B/c when I choose a software as a first step I would never get answers like Kersten's and that is exactly what I am looking for. As more possibiities as better. As I am specialised on ArcGIS and QGIS I always try to go this two ways parallel, but I think there might be better solutions. And I am eager to discover new pathes.

Comment: Once you show what you have tried and where you are stuck using a particular software I would expect answers like that of @Kersten to be provided by GIS practitioners who think there is a better way.  General questions can always be asked in the GIS Chat Room.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175398/interactive-and-dynamic-map-with-wind-data-in-r-leaflet/221137#221137

Answer (score 5):

A good starting point would be https://earth.nullschool.net/.

They use the following libraries to create this visualization:

- D3.js
- backbone.js
- when.js
- node.js

For further information you can take a look at the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/cambecc/earth).